# Login with fb: login doesn't seem to be working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I've seen this example at facebook, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php

define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'your app id ');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'your app secret');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']));

?>
```

All this documentation I found it on facebook so I just asumed that replacing some things would be enough.

I find an error/bug when it comes to this line

```
    <?php if ($cookie) { ?>
      Welcome <?= $user->name ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
```

The login doesn't return the name of the person who's logged in.

I've tried this

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    alert('session:' response.session + ' connection:' response.status);
window.location.reload();
});
```

This return session: undefined and connection: connected, so I don't understand where is the problem.

I don't know if it is because some bug (which I already heard about with this plugin) or not

Comment: What's the raw JSON look like before you decode it?

Comment: It appears to be empty, because I have this '$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']));' and then use a 'echo $user' but is not showing anything

Comment: How about the `$cookie`? Anything there? or did that fail too?

Comment: Same, it's empty, but if I 'echo $_COOKIE' then it gives me an array with an element, sadly my server is down right now and I cannot show you

Comment: Excellent; start adding some debugging lines to the `get_facebook_cookie()` routine and try to spot the bug in action.

Comment: Seems like it really is facebook, I used another example, this time the one where it shows your name/pic, it's just plain copy/paste code but it gives 'undefined' as your name and a broken link for the image

Comment: Have you tried creating a new facebook application to get a new ID and secret?  Maybe something is hosed up on facebook's side with your current app id.

Comment: Does `get_facebook_cookie()` return `null`? Also, how are you getting the user to authorise your application?